# How can I efficiently convert an angle (in radian) to an index from 0 to 7?

Tags: python, math, geometry, radians

I have an angle in radian, and I'd like to convert it into a value indexed from 0 to 7 in the following manner :

[image]

**Note** that `0 rad` should fall in the middle of the sector, etc.

What would be the most efficient way to do this, using simple math?

Comment: I don't know Python, but something like (4 theta / pi + 1/2) mod 8 ought to do it.

Comment: yeah, this is why I specified a programming language, because I'm a programmer, not a mathematician :)

Comment: Try `floor((theta + pi/8)/(pi/4))`

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia - The diagram implies he needs "round", not "floor".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each "slice" takes up `pi/4`. Following what @Beta said, you can do this:

```
def rad2slice(rad):
    return int((4 * rad / np.pi + .5) % 8)

# Quick test:
In [22]: [rad2slice(i*np.pi/4) for i in range(8)]                               
Out[22]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
import math

def angle_to_sector(angle_in_rads):
  sector_size_in_rads = 2*math.pi / 8
  offset_angle = (angle_in_rads + sector_size_in_rads/2) % (2*math.pi)
  sector = offset_angle // sector_size_in_rads
  return sector
```